# vector with unspecific size of element and number of elements

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, properties, propertygrid

I want to define some arbitrary properties for each point in some classes but the type and number of properties are not defined previously. So, I need to store them in a vector but I dont know how to define the vector that each element can be of not-specific size and has different number of field. The class is as follows:

```
class UnstructuredMesh
{
std::vector<size_t>     m_cellBegIndices;       //!< Cell Beginning Indices
std::vector<size_t>     m_faceBegIndices;       //!< Face Beginning Indices
std::vector<OSG::Pnt3f> m_points;               //!< Points
std::vector<????, ????> m_pointProperties;      //!< Point Properties
};
```

can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: How about using e.g. [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) or [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg By my question I mean all of the vector elements are the same size but their sizes are not determined previously and it will be determined in run-time but I think this one is to use for a vector which their elements has different sizes. Isn't it?

Comment: In that case it's not possible to use `std::vector` as it needs the contained type at compilation time. You could possibly do it using `void`*` and type-casting, but it have a bad code-smell. Also, when you say the size is fixed, but at runtime, it makes me guess that you already have a number of different structures and you just pick one of them when the program is running which means you indeed can use Boost Any (or unions), or possibly you can use `std::string` or a `std::vector<int8_t>` (or similar) for the data.

Comment: At this point it looks like you need to define a list of possible variations and then design a nice interface/base class that can be extended to meet all conceivable variation (although in practice this is very difficult). Then your vector can be filled with pointers to items of the base class type. I think this is what you're trying to do right? Just be careful about destruction.

Comment: @Ian yeah! something similar. I just tried to solve the problem with using a vector of floats. Then parse the floats and fill the variables based on the order of properties. Seems complex but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well given the comments I figured I'd give an example of what I suggested. Hard to know exactly what you're doing, but this assumes you're filling the vector with some kind of executable components that need to do different things.

I see you've already solved your problem, but something like below may render a more easily understood solution. Obviously the memory deallocation on the vector should be handled in some better form in a real application, and don't forget to include a virtual destructor in real-life. But this compiles and runs.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

class iface
{
public:
   virtual void execute() = 0;

};

class do_stuff_A : public iface
{
private:
   int A;
   int B;

public:
   do_stuff_A()
   {
      A = 1;
      B = 2;
   }

   void execute() override
   {
      printf("\nA is %d, B is %d", A, B);
   }
};

class do_stuff_B : public iface
{
private:
   double A;
   double B;
   double C;

public:
   do_stuff_B()
   {
      A = 1.1f;
      B = 2.2f;
      C = 3.2f;
   }

   void execute() override
   {
      printf("\nA is %f, B is %f, C is %f", A, B);
   }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

   std::vector<iface*> my_vec;

   my_vec.push_back(new do_stuff_A());
   my_vec.push_back(new do_stuff_B());

   my_vec[0]->execute();
   my_vec[1]->execute();

   Sleep(3000);

   for (int i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); i++)
   {
      delete my_vec[i];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: But then I have to define a class for each combination of properties and that's not possible in my case :(

Comment: Unless you can create a base class for all the properties you wish to add to this vector and make the properties themselves classes (or structs I guess). I've seen a very complicated implementation of something like this using templates, where data-types were defined to inherit from a common base class so that common operations could be done on them. A lot of times I will just elect to do more typing to make the design more explicit and less complicated, even if it creates a less elegant app.